# Angular 11 + Angular-clickgrid@2.25.0 + Build errors

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I have installed latest version of **angular-slickgrid** in Angular 11 project. After `ng build`, I have started getting these errors in `d.ts` files.
Could you please help me with the same?

Below are the logs from build :

```
ng build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/services/graphql.service.d.ts:18:5 - error TS2416: Property 'init' in type 'GraphqlService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BackendService'.
Type '(serviceOptions?: GraphqlServiceOption | undefined, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(serviceOptions?: BackendServiceOption | undefined, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void'.
Types of parameters 'serviceOptions' and 'serviceOptions' are incompatible.
Type 'BackendServiceOption | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GraphqlServiceOption | undefined'.
Property 'datasetName' is missing in type 'BackendServiceOption' but required in type 'GraphqlServiceOption'.

18 init(serviceOptions?: GraphqlServiceOption, pagination?: Pagination, grid?: any): void;
~~~~

node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/graphqlServiceOption.interface.d.ts:14:5
14 datasetName: string;
~~~~~~~~~~~
'datasetName' is declared here.
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/services/graphql.service.d.ts:54:5 - error TS2416: Property 'processOnPaginationChanged' in type 'GraphqlService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BackendService'.
Type '(event: Event, args: PaginationChangedArgs) => string' is not assignable to type '(event: Event | undefined, args: PaginationChangedArgs) => string'.
Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
Type 'Event | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Event'.

54 processOnPaginationChanged(event: Event, args: PaginationChangedArgs): string;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/services/grid-odata.service.d.ts:21:5 - error TS2416: Property 'init' in type 'GridOdataService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BackendService'.
Type '(serviceOptions: Partial, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(serviceOptions?: BackendServiceOption | undefined, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void'.
Types of parameters 'serviceOptions' and 'serviceOptions' are incompatible.
Type 'BackendServiceOption | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Partial'.

21 init(serviceOptions: Partial, pagination?: Pagination, grid?: any): void;
~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/services/grid-odata.service.d.ts:42:5 - error TS2416: Property 'processOnPaginationChanged' in type 'GridOdataService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BackendService'.
Type '(event: Event, args: PaginationChangedArgs) => string' is not assignable to type '(event: Event | undefined, args: PaginationChangedArgs) => string'.
Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
Type 'Event | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Event'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Event'.

42 processOnPaginationChanged(event: Event, args: PaginationChangedArgs): string;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/graphqlServiceApi.interface.d.ts:7:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'GraphqlServiceApi' incorrectly extends interface 'BackendServiceApi'.
The types of 'service.init' are incompatible between these types.
Type '(serviceOptions?: GraphqlServiceOption | undefined, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(serviceOptions?: BackendServiceOption | undefined, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void'.

7 export interface GraphqlServiceApi extends BackendServiceApi {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/models/odataServiceApi.interface.d.ts:4:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'OdataServiceApi' incorrectly extends interface 'BackendServiceApi'.
The types of 'service.init' are incompatible between these types.
Type '(serviceOptions: Partial, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void' is not assignable to type '(serviceOptions?: BackendServiceOption | undefined, pagination?: Pagination | undefined, grid?: any) => void'.
[0m
4 export interface OdataServiceApi extends BackendServiceApi {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/autoCompleteFilter.d.ts:64:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'AutoCompleteFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | ... 20 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

64 setValues(values: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/compoundDateFilter.d.ts:48:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'CompoundDateFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | ... 20 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

48 setValues(values: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/compoundInputFilter.d.ts:43:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'CompoundInputFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | "*z" | "EQ" | "GE" | "GT" | "NE" | "LE" | ... 14 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchTerm[]'.

43 setValues(values: SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/compoundSliderFilter.d.ts:43:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'CompoundSliderFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | ... 20 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

43 setValues(values: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/inputFilter.d.ts:37:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'InputFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: SearchTerm, operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | "*z" | "EQ" | "GE" | "GT" | "NE" | "LE" | ... 14 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchTerm'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchTerm'.

37 setValues(values: SearchTerm, operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/selectFilter.d.ts:52:5 - error TS2416: Property 'init' in type 'SelectFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(args: FilterArguments, isFilterFirstRender: boolean) => Promise' is not assignable to type '(args: FilterArguments, isFilterFirstRender?: boolean | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'isFilterFirstRender' and 'isFilterFirstRender' are incompatible.
Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

52 init(args: FilterArguments, isFilterFirstRender: boolean): Promise;
~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/selectFilter.d.ts:67:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'SelectFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | ... 20 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

67 setValues(values: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/nativeSelectFilter.d.ts:40:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'NativeSelectFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | ... 20 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

40 setValues(values: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/dateRangeFilter.d.ts:50:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'DateRangeFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(searchTerms: SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | "*z" | "EQ" | "GE" | "GT" | "NE" | "LE" | ... 14 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'searchTerms' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SearchTerm[]'.

50 setValues(searchTerms: SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/sliderFilter.d.ts:41:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'SliderFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | "a" | ... 20 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'values' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

41 setValues(values: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/angular-slickgrid/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/filters/sliderRangeFilter.d.ts:53:5 - error TS2416: Property 'setValues' in type 'SliderRangeFilter' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Filter'.
Type '(searchTerms: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[], operator?: "" | "*" | "LT" | OperatorType | "<>" | "!=" | "=" | "==" | ">" | ">=" | "<" | "<=" | ... 21 more ... | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(values: string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined) => void'.
Types of parameters 'searchTerms' and 'values' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | SearchTerm[]'.

53 setValues(searchTerms: SearchTerm | SearchTerm[], operator?: OperatorType | OperatorString): void;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

The other proposed answer, by @riteshk, was true at the time to get it working. However I did push a fix recently (with lot of effort) in the latest release of Angular-Slickgrid [version 2.26.1](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases/tag/v2.26.1). Angular-Slickgrid is now built with strict mode enabled and so this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently slickgrid code doesn't work well with angular strict mode https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode. You might want to disable it in **tsconfig.json**.

```
"strict": false
```